# Data Reporting in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have Excel Sheet with some data in it. Link will get you to the spreadsheet. 
I need to build a report that extract information from each months worksheet. All the worksheet is under same workbook.

It can be done with VLOOKUP, INDIRECT and COUNTIFS but I am still new to Excel and do not have clear idea of implementing altogether.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jruh09qfklntmqz/Book1.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the golden rule of spreadsheet design: Data in one sheet, reports in other sheets.

You are not doing yourself a favour by spreading the data entry over several sheets, one per month. This will make reporting very difficult.

Put all the data in one sheet and add a column for the date. Then you can build a pivot table with a few clicks and no formulas. Pivot tables allow filters, so you can filter by name and/or date.

[image]

Comment: I thought of doing Pivot table but the actual "Names" are quite long. Around 400 names and total 800 entries per month.

Comment: In your dropbox example you use data validation dropdowns. If there are not too many names for that dropdown, how come there are too many names for a pivot filter dropdown?

Comment: I have used only partial list for data validations. Actual validation list contain approximate 300 to 400 names. Really sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your data is not efficiently organized. You should have a table that looks more like this

```
Date    Name    Status
1-Apr-15    Keyur   Working
1-Apr-15    John    Disable
1-Apr-15    Jason   Enable
1-Apr-15    Keyur   Pending
1-Apr-15    Keyur   Working
1-Apr-15    Maria   Pending
1-May-15    Jason   disable
1-May-15    John    pending
1-May-15    Kane    pending
1-May-15    Brook   working
1-May-15    Kane    enable
1-May-15    Maria   pending
```

Using that you could create a pivot table. http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

With the pivot table you can organize your lists any way you want and count the pending, working and enable per month, quarter, year etc.